# Remove duplicate rows, but keep the entire row with the highest value in a certain cell

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

I have an excel sheet with 17 columns (column A to column S). Column A contains ID numbers, column C is a date column and column F contains values in time format (hh:mm). For the same date/day, some ID numbers contain two values in column F - usually a high number (many hours and min) and a low number (few minutes). If there is such a duplicate, I want the entire row containing the low value in column F to be deleted from the sheet.

I tried with Excel's "onboard" remove duplicates-function, but it didn't do the trick. Then I came across this piece of VBA code that removes the entire duplicate row, containing the highest value:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicatesKeepMin()
    Dim r As Integer, r2 As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim NextVal As Double

    r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A2:C" & r)
    rng.Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B2") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
        False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2 _
        :=xlSortNormal

    r2 = 2
    For i = 2 To r
        If Not NextVal = Range("A" & i) Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Copy Destination:=Range("D" & r2)
        r2 = r2 + 1
        NextVal = Range("A" & i + 1)
    End If
Next
rng.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm not entirely sure I understand the logic behind this, but I'm guessing this can be used as a starting Point (reversing the logic and adding a new restriction (if on the same day). If I change the orders from ascending to descending, it will take take the highest value. But I'm not sure how to put the extra restriction (the day restriction) in.

Thx!

Comment: What you want to delete, row or cell?

Comment: I want the entire row to be deleted ( which contains the lowest value)

Answer (score 0):

Here, my approach for your problem:

```
Public Sub deleteDuplicate()

    Dim row As Integer

    'Set the start row
    row = 2

    With Sheets("sheetname")

        'Loop until ID cell is blank
        Do While .Range("A" & row) <> ""

            innerRow = 1

            'Re-loop until ID cell is blank for checking
            Do While .Range("A" & innerRow) <> ""

                'If ID and date are equal
                If row <> innerRow And .Range("A" & row) = .Range("A" & innerRow) And .Range("C" & row) = .Range("C" & innerRow) Then

                    If .Range("F" & row) < .Range("F" & innerRow) Then

                        .Rows(row).Delete

                        row = row - 1

                        Exit Do

                    Else

                        .Rows(innerRow).Delete

                    End If

                End If

                'Increase inner looping row
                innerRow = innerRow + 1

            Loop

            'Increase row
            row = row + 1

        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```